# Display image caption with css3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a caption on my images. Caption should behave in two different ways. One is normal and second is hover. For better understanding I have added an image. check it.

[image]

Here I have already finished big part of this, But I can not display normal caption on the image correctly.

Can anybody tell me how I figure this out?

THIS is my HTML -

```
<div class="slideimages">
    <div id="box-1" class="box">
        <div class="fix-caption">
           <h3>Fix Caption</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
        </div>                  
        <a href="">     
            <img class="image_scale" src="images/4750.jpg"/>
            <span class="caption scale-caption">
            <h3>Scale Caption</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
             </span>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

MY [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zfr5c/) with CSS
Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfr5c/1/ - add a `z-index` and background color. That should get you started? (Edit: only tested in FF23)

Comment: Before I ask this question, I tried it with `z-index: 9000`, but I could not get it to work. is there any different between `z-idex: 90` and my one?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference, 9000 is just 'higher'. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I checked it on firefox, google chrome, safari, ie 8. In IE hover text not working.. can you tell me what is the reason for it?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support CSS3 transitions (I believe they are only supported as of IE10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS

```
.fix-caption {
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Your caption is there, just displaying behind the image...

Alternatively put the elements with `.fix-caption` lower in the DOM order, which will effectively give them a higher display order (note you'll still want a `background-color`).

**DEMO 1 (z-index)  :** http://jsfiddle.net/Zfr5c/3/

**DEMO 2 (DOM order):** http://jsfiddle.net/Zfr5c/2/

Comment: Thank for your answer. My problem have solved. But one question, in my hover caption, its text take little time to disappear from the image when I left mouse from image? Can you tell what is the reason for it?

Comment: @TNK you'll have to adjust your transition timings.

Comment: I am trying to get output something similar to this demo page's 6th effect - http://demo.hongkiat.com/css3-image-captions/index.html